# How to load html from clicking a div class button without page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I'm sorry for asking a simple question as I'm still learning html/css/js. What I want to do is to be able to click on this button that is a div class made from css and js, to load it's content without refreshing the page, which I believe requires ajax or jquery, but not sure how. Here is my github page [danielroberto.github.io](http://danielroberto.github.io) and the repo https://github.com/danielroberto/danielroberto.github.io so you can get an idea of what I mean. I basically want to click on any of the navigation buttons and then loads whatever content I want without redirecting to whole new html page. For example, when I want to click on the "photography" button, I want the button effect to happen while my images load on the bottom without redirecting to something like photography.html. Similar to clicking on the "design" button, I want it to transition and load my content.

Comment: Take a look at [this article on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX) or Google "Ajax tutorial."

Answer (score 1):

There is a wealth of resources on the net to get the intro you need to AJAX - the technique of loading parts of a webpage instead of the whole thing.

You correctly suggest that you could use the jQuery JavaScript library to do this - there are lots of alternatives, but that's easy to learn, and is widely used on the net. Tried and tested!

Start here: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_intro.asp

That would only be if you are planning to use some server-side technology to serve up your images.

If you are just going to manually set a list of images to show, and you want the buttons to cycle through these, then you're probably best just to build a carousel of some kind, using a jQuery carousel plugin, and include it all in your HTML markup from the beginning. Loads to choose from or get inspired by here: https://plugins.jquery.com/tag/carousel/.

Also, you should size your images to fit the screen you are serving them to. I recommend you look at using `srcset`. Your image on the test site was 4600px wide! Check this out: [https://css-tricks.com/responsive-images-youre-just-changing-resolutions-use-srcset/](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_intro.asp)

I hope it goes well. The early days can be hard work but you'll soon get the hang of it.

Comment: Yes, OP @DanielRoberto _"requires ajax or jquery"_ it's not ajax _**or**_ jquery — jquery is _one_ library that can help you do ajax.  You can also do ajax in plain js with no libraries, it's just more work.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily edit the html of an element when clicking a button using jQuery

HTML

```
    <div class="my-button">click here</div>
    <div class="my-content">init content</div>
```

JS

```
    contentElement = $('.my-content');

    $('.my-button').click(function() {
      contentElement.html('new content');
    });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jaxon58/zp9mvu38/

Answer (score 0):

You could store your content in a var in your js. Then when your button is clicked you can call the function which creates a text node or an element and append that to your div.

HTML

```
<button onClick="function()"></button>
<div id="show-data">
</div>
```

JS

```
var newText = 'Stuff here';
function function() {
    var div;
    div = document.getElementById('show-data');
    div.appendChild(document.createTextNode(newText));
}
```